# .htaccess autoindex not working, 403 error

Tags: apache-2.4, centos6

I want to enable the Directory Index with Apache 2.4 on CentOS 6. First I edited `httpd.conf` but it didn't work so I ended up with placing a `.htaccess` file in the desired folder, hoping that no setting could override the `.htaccess` directives.
But it didn't work either, when I request the directory I get a 403.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Checked that `.htaccess` file is working by putting garbage in it
2. Put those lines in `httpd.conf`:

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www/path/to/folder">
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Wrote those lines in `.htaccess`:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex disabled
   Require all granted
   Allow from all
   Options +Indexes
   ```
4. Checked if `mod_autoindex` is enabled
5. Ran `apache2ctl configtest` -> Syntax OK
6. Changed file and directory ownership and group to apache, `.htaccess` permissions to 666

But nothing works, I just get the fancy "Testing 123.." Apache/CentOS Error page...

After Michael Hamptons comment I added the following step:

7. Set `httpd.conf` error level to 'debug'

   -> Nothing is logged in error_log

   -> access_log logs just:

   ```
   "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 4897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
   ```

   ... followed by 4 font requests fo the Error page, which seems to me like I am looking in the wrong file, or the error level setting doesn't work?

Comment: Check your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that there is a file named `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` which has  a directive that overrides the one in the .htaccess file:

By commenting this line out I solved my problem:

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    #Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer found on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349672/apache-wont-autoindex)